# Why is Ruby on Rails lacking on documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Configuring the PHP debuggers was so hard that I can't even imagine myself using the Rails documentation by blogging. The problem looks easy to solve: write the documentation, so why doesn't anyone do it? I'm thinking that if you don't have a way to learn it, you have to ask the ones who know it, so who can know it and why?

Comment: This is a subjective question (I agree with vise that api.rubyonrails.org is a great resource) without a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so called "lack of documentation" view rests in the eyes of the beholder. 
Frankly I don't see the problem. Most of the time you can find what you need on api.rubyonrails.org, or if you're looking for something more friendly on guides.rubyonrails.org.

Blogs may provide some extra insight on some of the features, but the rails rdoc is king.

Answer (score 3):

Well, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of resources that together make Rails very easy to learn.  The API does have a learning curve, and it could definitely be better, but once you get over the initial learning curve with Rails, the API starts to feel a lot more helpful.

The Rails Guides are a very good place to start.

These are the other resources that make Rails very easy to learn:
Railscasts.com

Railsforum.com

Amazing video tutorials here:
www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-rbar/everyday-active-record
http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-rbforms/mastering-rails-forms

The Rails books from Pragmatic Programmer are excellent.  It's worth buying Rails Recipes, Advanced Rails Recipes and Agile Web Development with Rails.

If you buy all these books and the videos, you're still looking at less than $100.  Considering what they empower you to do with Rails, it's a very good deal.